# How to install serverless on an ubuntu server

Tags: serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy lambda code, using aws serverless.

I am using a Virtual private server for that task, and i cannot properly run the serverless command. Each time, he throw me this error :

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/essentials/index.js:21
        throw reason;
        ^

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at getChromeVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/supports-color/browser.js:5:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/supports-color/browser.js:14:22)
```

I have installed chromium, and the 'google-chrome-stable' package, but without success.

Comment: Have you tried updating your nodejs version and reinstalling the serverless package?

Comment: Yes, i tried, but that didn't work, I have tried many things, but finally, what worked was to install ubuntu graphical packages.